# Weird white and black boxes in model

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

So I was following a tutorial for beginners and I reached a point where I was using texture paint. After I finished I noticed a weird white and black boxes. I looked it up, but couldn't find a answer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange.  When you have a problem like this, it can be helpful to post your blend file on the internet and then link to it so that people trying to help you can do so as quickly as possible. When following a tutorial I'd usually suggest linking to it, as that might provide helpful information to the responders, but in this case we're probably all aware of what tutorial you're talking about.  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your *Image Texture* you are using to color the donut has some diferent color in the corners so that part where you see the grid type patern is where the corners meet.

**To fix this:**

- You sould can paint all the corners with the same color

**An image of a donut I made to recreate the problem:**

[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't think of it this way. Thank you!